# Shouldn't the [unknown-title] tag be replaced with the [identify-this-song] one?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I've just encountered the [unknown-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-title) tag: shouldn't it be replaced with the [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If anyone wants to get a little work towards their [Strunk & White](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), go ahead and burn the [unknown-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-title) tag.

Comment: Just a little FYI, using the tag [merge functionality](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/admin/merge-tags?removetag=unknown-title) you, as a moderator, can actually (silently) merge a tag into another one (and also rename it) without the necessaity to edit all the questions that use it manually.

Comment: I debated that, but there were only a handful of questions.  On a larger site, I would have chosen that route.